# Authentication url not working on Icecast

Tags: audio-streaming, shoutcast, icecast

Error not loading authentication.

> [2015-04-07  13:44:22] EROR auth/get_authenticator Auth URL disabled

I saw github issue (https://github.com/karlheyes/icecast-kh/issues/32).
So I installed curllib-devl, but I catch the error.

Centos release 6.6 (Final)

```
<mount type="default">
</mount>
<mount type="normal">
  <mount-name>/ices</mount-name>
  <public>1</public>
  <authentication type="url">
    <option name="listener_add" value="http://localhost/hoge/web/app_dev.php/listener-joined" />
    <option name="listener_remove" value="http://localhost/hoge/web/app_dev.php/listener-left" />
  </authentication>
</mount>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are official Icecast 2.4.1 packages for CentOS in the EPEL repositories. URL authentication will work just fine with those.

http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/repoview/icecast.html

[Generic instructions on enabling EPEL repositories](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL#How_can_I_use_these_extra_packages.3F)

If you installed from sources, make sure to remove all those files first to avoid confusion. Usually they are confined to  `/usr/local`, which makes this easy.